# Dynamically generating a jQuery Datepicker with altFields

Tags: jquery, datepicker, livequery

I'm dynamically generating datepicker's by simply appending the field HTML to a div:

```
<input type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" name="tier[2][publication_date]" id="publication_date_2" size="10" maxlength="10" tabindex="6" class="publication_date hasDatepicker">
<input type="hidden" name="tier[2][publication_date_db]" id="publication_date_db_2" value="">
```

Due to the way we store dates, we have a separate field (altfield) for the datepicker which stores our database formatted date selected by the user.

To handle selection of the multiple date pickers I assign a class and use livequery in order to detect onClicks after the page has loaded:

```
$(".publication_date").livequery(function() {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd M yy",
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                        console.log(inst);
                    }
                });
            });
```

I have a problem in that, how does the datepicker know which altfield to populate? On a single datepicker, one would normally include:

```
altField: '#start_date_datepicker_altfield', 
altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
```

for the population to occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the documentation says it takes a selector, but it can also take a jQuery object, so just use [`$(this).next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the hidden field, like this:

```
$(".publication_date").livequery(function() {
   $(this).datepicker({
      altField: $(this).next(), 
      altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      dateFormat: "dd M yy",
      changeYear: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        console.log(inst);
      }
   });
});
```

Since most of the plugins boil down to `$(input)` that input can be a selector *or* a jQuery object or a DOM element and it'll still work just fine :)

Comment: Tsk tsk, creating two jQuerys where one would do... ;-) (Nice approach, though.)

Comment: @TJCrowder - It creates a jQuery object every click anyway (either approach): `$(altField).each(function() { $(this).val(dateStr); });`, little cost + much easier to maintain IMO :)

Comment: Right, but your iterator function creates one *twice* on each click: First on the function's first line (`$(this).datepicker`) and then again on its second line (`altField: $(this).next(),`). Just a friendly nit-pick (just a bit of a joke, really), any performance implication is *vastly* overwhelmed by the fact it's an event handler anyway... :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder - I think you missed something :) `.livequery()` != `.live()` :) The performance sink is actually that's it's `.livequery()` looking for new elements :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used livequery, but from the looks of it, you can get the `id` of the matched element from `this.id`. In your example HTML, that will be "publication_date_2", from which it's relatively easy to create the necessary ID for the altfield "publication_date_db_2" (you can make it even easier by changing your strategy of naming the field).

So perhaps:

```
$(".publication_date").livequery(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            console.log(inst);
        },
        altField: "#" + this.id.replace("_date_", "_date_db_"),
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realised this.

Comment: How do you propose changing the naming convention of fields?

Comment: @user275074: Actually, the one you have is easy enough (see above). I'd've probably used a prefix, but it doesn't matter...